# "I can't confirm all what he said" versus "I can't confirm all of what he said"

Tags: prepositions

I want to know if this sentence is correct without the preposition *of* in it.

> I can't confirm all what he said.

Should I instead write the following sentence?

> I can't confirm all of what he said.

Regarding usage, I did a quick check of COHA and found some examples that did not use *of*.

> I don't know all what she knew.

Is this sentence correct?

Answer (score 6):

You need "of" in standard English.

---

Consider the following sentence:

> The monster (that) I saw in the cave
> was hideous.

*That* is a relative pronoun: it refers back to *the monster* (the antecedent), and it introduces a subordinate clause of which it is itself the object, *that I saw in the cave* (the relative clause). We could use *what* here:

> What I saw in the cave was hideous.

As you see, *what* has swallowed its antecedent: the relative pronoun *what* always does that, because it always includes an antecedent. If the antecedent must be specified, *what* is impossible. Apart from that, it functions just like *that* or *which*. In your *of* sentence, if I were to replace your *what* by a *that*, it would look like this:

> I can't confirm all of [the things]
> that she said.

I was forced to supply the antecedent that was hidden within *what*, because *that* requires an antecedent. I made something up, *these things*. This all works fine. However, consider your sentence without *of*:

> *I can't confirm all what he said.

If I replaced *what*, I'd get:

> I can't confirm all [the things] that
> he said.

This might look all right, but think about the antecedent: what is it here exactly? The problem is that the antecedent is not just *the things*, but also *all*: "what did he say? he said all the things; what can't I confirm? I can't confirm all the things". The adjective *all* is part of the antecedent, which is why it too should disappear if you use *what*:

> I can't confirm what he said.

---

That is why your sentence without *of* doesn't work in standard English. There might be dialects in which this happens regularly, though. Normally it should be one of the following constructions:

> I can't confirm all he said. (*That* is implicit.)
>
> I can't confirm all of what he said.
>
> I can't confirm what he said.

Comment: Wow, proof by contradiction! nice.